# Renaming object from in aws s3 console, with IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Created an IAM user, with S3 full access (S3:*) on a specific ARN (only one bucket). Upload and delete works, but not able to rename or copy/paste.

Here is my IAM policy.

```
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1490288788",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: How are you renaming / copying & pasting? Are you doing it via the S3 management console? With the above policy, they wouldn't even be able to use the console because it doesn't give permissions to list buckets.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing it from s3 management console. And yes, you're right, they won't allow listing bucket, but i can use the bucket link to go directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the correct solution, but giving `ListAllMyBuckets` permission worked for me.

I just added another statement along with the previous one.

```
{
    "Sid": "Stmt1490288788",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
    ]
}{
    "Sid": "Stmt1490289746001",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
       "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
    ],
    "Resource": [
       "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    ]
}
```

So this policy lists all the buckets, but only allow put/delete/get access to the specific bucket. Still wondering what's the relation between rename/copy & list all bucket permissions.

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't actually rename functionality in S3 itself, some interfaces may try and implement it by using S3 PUT object copy and DELETE actions behind the scenes.  Their implementation may require other bucket-level permissions to complete, which is why it may be failing with your policy.  Try this:

```
{
    "Sid": "Stmt1490288788",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
    ]
}
```

The difference being this grants permissions to actions performed on the bucket itself (the first resource declared), as well as the objects in the bucket (the second resource declared).

Comment: Actually i'm in the aws console itself. Not a third party tool to access s3. I see rename option in s3 objects there. May be they are doing COPY & DELETE.

Comment: And i already have a similar bucket policy.

{
            "Sid": "Stmt1490288788",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::768787887788:user/dsd-user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }

Comment: @RobinCSamuel *"May be they are doing COPY & DELETE"*.  Correct.  The console does copy and delete, to *emulate* a move, because S3 does not actually have a move operation.

Comment: Adding the above statement does nothing. I was able to rename from console by giving list all buckets permission.