# Allowing IAM user to rename object in S3 Bucket without ListAllMyBuckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been searching the web and mostly amazon docs all day and couldn't find an answer to this issue.

I have (root user) several Buckets in AWS S3.

I've assigned a new bucket to a new IAM user and I don't want him to see all the buckets names
under: https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets
(He can access his bucket at: https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/HISBUCKETNAME)

However, I also want the user to be able to rename file in his bucket. This is impossible if I remove `ListAllMyBuckets` from his IAM policy.

So in the working user IAM policy I have

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately now the users can see all the buckets in https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets (though he doesn't have access to them).

Once I remove `"s3:ListAllMyBuckets"`, the user get access denied when trying to **rename** a file in his bucket.

Is there a way to allow the user to rename a file in his bucket without him having access to the list of all the bucket names (I.E. without ListAllMyBuckets)?

Thanks

Comment: This https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/ might help you. Maybe the policy should be made specificly for that user/bucket, or if it is shared, the files that should not get accessed, should be placed in another one

Comment: Thanks, this article talks  about restricting access  to a bucket. All my other buckets have restricted access. I want to restrict the access to list all the buckets (it doesn't have a policy for it) while still allowing renaming of file name in the allowed bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct!

It seems that it is not possible to Rename an object in the Amazon S3 console unless the user also has `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` permission.

I tried many combinations (including giving `s3:*` on the specific bucket rather than on `*`) and could not get it to work without `ListAllMyBuckets`.

These pages seem to agree:

- [Renaming object from in aws s3 console, with IAM user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42996548/174777)
- ["Unable to move or rename S3 object using web console" | Ivan Bliskavka](https://bliskavka.com/2021/09/06/unable-to-rename-s3-object-in-web-console/)
- [AWS Rename permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63348973/174777)

Comment: Yes, got confirmations from more people. seems to be a bug. I posted a bug report on amazon's repost forum: [https://repost.aws/questions/QU-HSbk4QuSIiJNeZnf8S8uw/bug-report-impossible-to-rename-object-in-s3-bucket-without-listallmybuckets](https://repost.aws/questions/QU-HSbk4QuSIiJNeZnf8S8uw/bug-report-impossible-to-rename-object-in-s3-bucket-without-listallmybuckets)